# CAPWAP traffic flow

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, capwap

when a client wants to send inter-VLAN traffic, does this mean that the traffic first goes from the AP to the Wireless Controller (WLC) through CAPWAP tunnel, and then the WLC sends it to the default gateway of the source VLAN?

Comment: Also, Wi-Fi uses different SSIDs instead of VLANs. The WLC can put traffic from different SSIDs onto different VLANs. You question would be more accurate if you ask about different networks, rather than VLANs.

Answer (score 5):

Exactly.  The WLAN is a layer 2 domain just like a wired LAN. The WLC bridges the WLAN to the wired LAN.